# Can't debug a Meteor project in WebStorm and node 8.9.0

Tags: webstorm

I have updated to node v8.9.0 and now I am getting this error when trying to run Debug.

```
--debug-brk=50085 is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

I am in a Meteor 1.6 project, which uses node v8.8.0

I have tried to disable and enable all node ad JS related plugins but it didn't help.

WebStorm version: 2017.2.5

Is there anything I can do or is it a bug which needs to be fixed by WebStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-28311](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28311) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: meanwhile fixed in the latest release candidate